# AWS CDK deploy using role

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

You can find the cdk app that you can use to replicate my issue here [varvay/issue-replication.git](https://github.com/varvay/issue-replication.git). The usage instruction explained in the `README`

I need to deploy CDK app using a role by issuing this command

```
cdk -r arn:aws:iam::000000000000:role/fooRole deploy
```

but then an error thrown

```
Assuming role failed: User: arn:aws:iam::000000000000:user/fooUser is not authorized to 
perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::000000000000:role/barRole
```

to be sure, I tried to simulate it by assuming the `arn:aws:iam::000000000000:role/barRole` role using `arn:aws:iam::000000000000:role/fooRole` in AWS IAM Policy Simulator and it works just fine. One thing that bothers me is that the error said that a `User` tried to assume the role, not `Role`.

Why is that? or should I assume the `fooRole`, update the AWS-related environment variable and then deploy? if so then what's the point of having `-r` option on `cdk`

as additional information, here's the trust relationship of the `barRole`

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam:: 000000000000:root"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

also I even tried to attach `AdministratorAccess` AWS managed policy to the `fooRole` used to deploy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to fulfill my needs by creating a bash script to switch to the destination role and use the credential to perform the CDK command as the script written below,

```
#!/bin/bash
unset AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
unset AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
unset AWS_SESSION_TOKEN

AWS_CREDENTIAL=$(aws sts assume-role \
--role-arn <destination role ARN> \
--role-session-name <role session name> \
--duration-seconds 3600)

export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$(echo $AWS_CREDENTIAL \
| jq -r '.Credentials''.AccessKeyId')

export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$(echo $AWS_CREDENTIAL \
| jq -r '.Credentials''.SecretAccessKey')

export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=$(echo $AWS_CREDENTIAL \
| jq -r '.Credentials''.SessionToken')

cdk deploy

unset AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
unset AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
unset AWS_SESSION_TOKEN
```

Comment: For anyone looking for `jq`, you can find it here - https://jqlang.github.io/jq/

Answer (score 0):

So there are 2 ways you might be running `cdk deploy` command from.

1- You're running this command from your local computer's CLI using IAM keys. In this case, this role must be assumable by the AWS account (IAM User) being used.

2- You're running this command from any AWS service (cicd agent on EC2 instance for e.g.:) then the role attached with the instance should be allowed to assume this deployment role.

mention how you're running this command and you might get a better answer.

UPDATE:
Based on the updated question:

Add `assume role` part in your IAM USER not your deployment role. Your IAM User from which you're trying to deploy should be allowed to assume the role through which the CDK will be deployed.

To diagramise it a bit:

```
(IAM-USER -> Assume -> Role) -> cdk deploy
```

Comment: I've edited and enriched my question. I ran the command from my local computer's CLI using `fooUser` IAM User as my default credential configuration. Can you help to explain how to make it works? Thankyou

Comment: yes it does works, tried that before but I want to rely all the permission management to the role, not user group. actually it works when I assume the role using aws cli and the perform cdk deployment, but then the thing that bothers me is what the use of `-r` option on the cdk cli if it doesn't assume the specified role then use it for the deployment, instead it use the defined AWS credentials in the configuration?

Comment: It looks like you don't understand the concept completely. You're on your machine which can't assume IAM role. You're using user keys to access AWS services and this "user" will run this CDK on your behalf. So this user has to convert itself into this role (this proc is called assuming roles). 

To understand it better, attach this IAM Role to EC2 instance and run cdk command on EC2; then you don't have to assume role

Comment: so `-r` option will not assume the mentioned role on the behalf of the user? what exactly the purpose of `-r` option in cdk?

Comment: I've created a cdk app to replicate my issue along with the usage instruction in the `README`. The link attached on the top of the question

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the process of cross account role accessing, as is written in your error message.

I assume that you start with AWS configuration for one account, lets call it "Provisioning" and then you need to assume role in different account (dev or prod) depending on branches or something ?

I smell an error in setup of cross account roles.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html

One possibility is : the Rolle you want to assume, does not have your provisioning account as trusted entity.

Another is : the user which is trying to assume the role, does not have the policy for that.

Just follow the tutorial from AWS and see what is missing in your setup :)

Comment: nope, all the resources and roles under a single AWS account. I've tried to simulate it on the AWS IAM Policy Simulator by assuming the destination role from the middleman role which is works, also assuming the middleman role from the user which is also works. it does works when I assume the middleman role from aws cli and deploy the cdk app, it just doesn't works when I put the middleman role's ARN on the `-r` cdk option

Comment: I've created a cdk app to replicate my issue along with the usage instruction in the `README`. The link attached on the top of the question