# Call CDK Deploy in another AWS Account from Fargate Task

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-cdk, aws-fargate

I have two accounts A and B. I want to deploy a stack using CDK in Account A by running cdk synth and cdk deploy in an ECS Task in Account B.

I created a role in account A with administrator access and granted permissions to Account B to be able to assume the role. Then the ECS task spins up in Account B and runs the following:

```
role_arn = "arn of Account A role which has admin access"

print("Synthesizing stack...")
sb.run(f"cdk --role-arn {role_arn} synth", shell=True)

print("Deploying stack...")
sb.run(f"cdk --role-arn {role_arn} deploy", shell=True)
```

This fails with the following error:

```
Could not assume role in target account using current credentials (which are for account 614863243217) User: arn:aws:sts::<B_account_id>:assumed-role/ecs-fargate-role/65dd98a9c327410 is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::<A_account_id>:role/cdk-hnb659fds-deploy-role-473038482210-us-east-2 . Please make sure that this role exists in the account. If it doesn't exist, (re)-bootstrap the environment with the right '--trust', using the latest version of the CDK CLI.
```

Looks like it's not using the role I created to deploy the stack. Is there a way to assume the role I created and call CDK synth and deploy?

The role I created in Account A looks like this along with it's trust policy:

**Permissions Policy**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Trust Relationships**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<AccountB>:root"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

I've also tried the following to "assume" the role in ecs.

```
role_arn = stack_json["role_arn"]
aws_region = stack_json["region"]
assumed_role_object = sts_client.assume_role(
    RoleArn=role_arn,
    RoleSessionName="AssumeRoleSession1"
)
credentials = assumed_role_object['Credentials']
p = Popen(['aws configure'], stdin=PIPE, shell=True)
aws_configure_str = f"{credentials['AccessKeyId']}\n{credentials['SecretAccessKey']}\n{aws_region}\njson\n"
p.communicate(input=bytes(aws_configure_str, 'utf-8'))
```

This writes the credentials for the default aws cli.

I've also tried passing in the credentials like this:

```
sb.run(f"cdk deploy", shell=True, env={
    "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID": credentials['AccessKeyId'],
    "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY": credentials['SecretAccessKey'],
    "AWS_DEFAULT_REGION": aws_region,
})
```

But when I look at the logs it says:

```
AWS Access Key ID [None]: AWS Secret Access Key [None]: Default region name [None]: Default output format [None]: Loaded stack_json
```

and the error says:
Deployment failed: Error: Need to perform AWS calls for account , but no credentials have been configured

Comment: you need to pass ENV variable to the Task I think : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/taskdef-envfiles.html

Comment: How did you grant the permissions? You need to do it in both accounts. A much better way is to do it natively with `cdk bootstrap --trust`, by the way. But if you're doing `cdk deploy` from an ECS task, you're probably not after super canonical methods.

Comment: I created an IAM role in account A (where stack needs to be deployed) and then the ECS role has administrator access (for now since I'm only testing)

Comment: Does the role include Account B in its trust policy?

Comment: Also, is the target environment bootstrapped?

Comment: Yes - I've updated the question to include more details as well

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this by writing a script to run cdk deploy and setting the environment variables inside of the script instead of passing them in the env variable in subprocess. The answer here helped me write the script: [AWS CDK deploy using role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73065768/aws-cdk-deploy-using-role)